# How to import Apache access log into MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, ruby, perl, apache

What is the recommended approach to import Apache access log into a MySQL table? I am thinking of a ruby/perl script + a cron job. It'll be great if there is an example or reference.

I am not sure how to handle the bookmarking of the last log entry in last import either. Suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Import (i.e. by yourself) or write directly (i.e. by apache) ?

Answer (score 3):

Do you own the customlog format? Or do you have to live with whatever is there? if you own the format you can easily delimit the fields (with tabs for example) and its pretty trivial to import.

```
LogFormat "%{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}t\t%s\t%h\t%{ClientIP}i\t%U%q\t%{Host}i\t%B\tc1w1402@dc1app14\t%m\t%{User-Agent}i\t%{Referer}i\tDRH\t%T\t%f\t%{Via}i" ezimport
```

Comment: I can change the default `LogFormat` but rather not to, for compatibility reason. Is it possible for apache (on CentOS) to write 2 logs (one as default, another for MySQL import)?

Comment: Yes, you can do many of them which is what the 'ezimport' indicates at the tail end.

Answer (score 1):

If you can write PERL script then try out mod_perl to log directly to database... for the reference check [link](http://perl.apache.org/docs/tutorials/tips/mod_perl_tricks/mod_perl_tricks.html#Logging_to_a_relational_database) .

Answer (score 0):

```
LogFormat "yourFormat" yourLog

<VirtualHost example.com>
    ServerName example.com
    CustomLog /yourPath yourLog
</VirtualHost>
```